# Problem with jquery and hammer.js when using

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hammer.js

I created a jquery function to be able to scroll a list of items back and forth, and it works perfectly with the mouse wheel.
Now I plan to use hammer.js to apply the same logic with touch, but I am failing miserably.

My function:

```
$.fn.scrollToNearest = function (delta) {
        var direction = delta > 0 ? "prev" : "next"; // Get the direction of the scroll.
        var elementToScroll = $(this)[direction](); // Get the element that should be scrolled into view.
    
        // Scroll the element into view.
        if (elementToScroll.length) {
            var id = elementToScroll.attr("id");
            document.querySelector("#" + id).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "end",
            });
        }
        return this; // Needed for other methods to be able to chain off of scrollToPreviousOrNext.
};
```

In an attempt to use hammerjs I have tried swipe and pan events without success, how can I create a method that has the same logic but touch?